# Z3-SMT-LIB on line is able to prove the left cancellation and iZ3 on line is able to prove the righ cancellation

Tags: z3

Z3 -SMT-LIB on line is able to prove the left cancellation property in groups:

((x*y) = (x*z)) => (y=z).

Run the proof on line [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/EI0l)

Z3-SMT-LIB on line is not able to prove the right cancellation property in groups:

((y*x)=(z*x)) => (y=z)

iZ3 on line is able to prove the right cancellation property in groups.

Run the proof on line [here](http://rise4fun.com/iZ3/L3f)

iZ3 on line is not able to prove the left cancellation property.

What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: I think that the reason is that Z3-SMT-LIB on line depends on the master branch of Z3; but iZ3 on line depends on the unstable branch of Z3. Do you agree?

Comment: I'm not sure what the "SMT-LIB" version of Z3 is, but in general the binary on rise4fun is updated manually, so it is some version between the last master release and the current unstable branch. Therefore, it is to be expected that they behave differently for some formulas.